# Can't post photo to user app album. Got OAuthException code: 368

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, photo

Our application using publish_stream permissions to post game screenshots to user app album. But when user click button to post photo through open graph api, he get OAuthException code: 368 and Facebook log out him. After user log in after this he get message:

> Spam Warning Sometimes spammers create fake pages that look like
>   Facebook or another website. These pages usually offer you a great
>   deal if you do something in return (ex: get free plane tickets when
>   you copy and paste this special access token). It looks like you
>   pasted sensitive info about your Facebook account onto on of these
>   pages. As a result, your account started spreading spam.
>
> Don't worry, we've secured your account.

When we first add this feature to app it worked fine, after few days we started to get this error. After few month photo posting started to work again but after few days was blocked again.
In the documentation there are nothing about this problem and we don't know what to do. Please help us to fix this problem.

Comment: What values do your app insights show for spam reports?

Comment: on 17k posted photos got 20 spam reports. For stream publish 0.2226 Spam Reports / 10K Impressions

Comment: Any chance you're doing something against policy like including a prefilled message or URL in the photo caption?

Comment: No, any actions against policy. And still we are getting this error. Two weeks api is working, then two weeks getting this error, then again..